# An easy way to set the active tab using controllers and a usercontrol in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, user-interface, tabs

How do I create tabbed navigation with the "Current" tab highlighted in the UI?

Comment: Please phrase these in the form of a question first, and then provide the answer as a separate post. I'll remove my downvote when I see you've fixed it. Otherwise I'll have to close it as 'not a real question'.

Comment: The question was so big and now so small :P haha

Comment: Did he wrote the question and the answer in the sames post?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins Yes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before MVC I looked at the file path and figured out which tab was currrent. Now it's a lot easier, you can assign the current tab based on the current controller.

Check it out ...

Most of the work happens in the usercontrol.

```
public partial class AdminNavigation : ViewUserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This hold a collection of controllers and their respective "tabs." Each Tab should have at least one controller in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, string> dict = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    public AdminNavigation()
    {
        dict.Add(typeof(BrandController), "catalog");
        dict.Add(typeof(CatalogController), "catalog");
        dict.Add(typeof(GroupController), "catalog");
        dict.Add(typeof(ItemController), "catalog");
        dict.Add(typeof(ConfigurationController), "configuration");
        dict.Add(typeof(CustomerController), "customer");
        dict.Add(typeof(DashboardController), "dashboard");
        dict.Add(typeof(OrderController), "order");
        dict.Add(typeof(WebsiteController), "website");
    }

    protected string SetClass(string linkToCheck)
    {
        Type controller = ViewContext.Controller.GetType();
        // We need to determine if the linkToCheck is equal to the current controller using dict as a Map
        string dictValue;
        dict.TryGetValue(controller, out dictValue);

        if (dictValue == linkToCheck)
        {
            return "current";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then in your .ascx part of the usercontol call into the SetClass method to check the link against the dict. Like so:

```
<li class="<%= SetClass("customer") %>"><%= Html.ActionLink<CustomerController>(c=>c.Index(),"Customers",new{@class="nav_customers"}) %></li>
```

All you need now is the CSS to highlight your current tab. There are a bunch of different ways to do this, but you can get started with some ideas here: http://webdeveloper.econsultant.com/css-menus-navigation-tabs/
Oh, and don't forget to put the usercontrol on your page (or MasterPage) ...

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("AdminNavigation"); %>
```

Comment: Does IDictionary work? It looks like it should be Dictionary instead.

Comment: What about when one controller has two actions?

Comment: @Anthony - this code works, it's in production now.
@Anthony2 - you mean you want a different tab highlighted per controller action? This won't help that. I'd suggest putting your controller specific nav in a user control and declare which tab to make active when embedding the UC in the page.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote some simple helper classes to solve this problem. The solution looks att both which controller that is used as well as which action in the controller.

```
public static string ActiveTab(this HtmlHelper helper, string activeController, string[] activeActions, string cssClass)  
{  
     string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.Controller.  
     ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
     string currentController = helper.ViewContext.Controller.  
     ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();  
     string cssClassToUse = currentController == activeController &&  
                            activeActions.Contains(currentAction)  
                            ? cssClass  
                            : string.Empty;  
     return cssClassToUse;  
}
```

You can the call this extension method with:

```
Html.ActiveTab("Home", new string[] {"Index", "Home"}, "active")
```

This will return "active" if we are on the HomeController in either the "Index" or the "Home" action. I also added some extra overloads to ActiveTab to make it easier to use, you can read the whole blog post on: [http://www.tomasjansson.com/blog/2010/05/asp-net-mvc-helper-for-active-tab-in-tab-menu/](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-helper-for-active-tab-in-tab-menu/)

Hope this will help someone.

Regards,
--Tomas

Comment: @tomas-jansson It seems the URL no longer resolves...is it now http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-mvc-helper-for-active-tab-in-tab-menu/ (?)

Answer (score 3):

One method I am using on a current project - this also helps for other page-specific CSS needs.

First, an HTML helper that returns a string that represents the current controller and action:

```
public static string BodyClass(RouteData data) {
   return string.Format("{0}-{1}", data.Values["Controller"], data.Values["Action"]).ToLower();
}
```

Then, add a call to this helper in your master page:

```
<body class="<%=AppHelper.BodyClass(ViewContext.RouteData) %>">
...
</body>
```

Now, you can target specific pages with your CSS. To answer your exact question about navigation:

```
#primaryNavigation a { ... }
.home-index #primaryNavigation a#home { ... }
.home-about #primaryNavigation a#about { ... }
.home-contact #primaryNavigation a#contact { ... }
/* etc. */
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC's default `Site.css` comes with a class named `'selectedLink'` which should be used for this.

Add the following to your `ul` list in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{
    var controller = @HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}
<ul id="menu">                
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = controller == "Home" ? "selectedLink" : "" })</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I know this is not clean. But just a quick and dirty way to get things rolling without messing with partial views or any of that sort.