# Better way to get active page link in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I want a specific menu link to be active at a given page, I'm using this approach in Razor:

On the master layout I have these checks:

```
var active = ViewBag.Active;
const string ACTIVE_CLASS = "current";

if (active == "home")
{
    ViewBag.ActiveHome = ACTIVE_CLASS;
}
if (active == "products")
{
    ViewBag.ActiveProducts = ACTIVE_CLASS;
}
```

etc.

The html menu on the master layout:

```
<ul>
<li class="@ViewBag.ActiveHome"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="@ViewBag.ActiveProducts"><a href="@Url.Action("index", "products")">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

When specifying which layout page to use on a different view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Active = "home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Is there a better approach to sepcify active links, than the one I'm currently using?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

A better approach is to use a HTML helper:

```
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class MenuExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string text,
        string action, 
        string controller
    )
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<ul>
    @Html.MenuItem("Home", "Home", "Home")
    @Html.MenuItem("Products", "Index", "Products")
</ul>
```

To make the above work you need your views to recognize your extension: In Web.config in the Views folder, add `<add namespace="yourNamespacehere.Helpers" />` inside the namespaces tag. Then build your project and close and re-open the view you are adding this to.

then based on the current action and controller the helper will add or not the `active` class when generating the anchor.

Comment: Looks like those mvc html helpers is a great idea, I might look more into that. Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Nice! I wanted to do this but couldn't figure out how to work out the active controller and action from inside an html helper.

Comment: Needed the same -- exactly -- and this did the trick. We must both be using Bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you put this custom helper?

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'MenuItem' and no extension method 'MenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Fergal, make sure you have brought the namespace in which the extension method is defined into scope in the view.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify for fellow newbies to C# and MVC 3, here is what I had to do: create Helpers folder on root, create a class, MenuExtensions.cs, with the above code in this folder. To the top of the file add 
`using System.Web.Mvc;`
`using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`

In Web.config in the Views folder, add `<add namespace="yourNamespacehere.Helpers" />` inside the namespaces tag.

Comment: How do you bring the namespace extension method into scope in the view? I have added the class in a Helpers folder and have added the namespace to the webconfig under <pages><namespaces></namespaces></pages>

Comment: I am receiving the same error: System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'MenuItem' and no extension method 'MenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: newbies to razor, if you are running visual studio in safe mode intellisense won't show this extension method.

Comment: @Fergal, It's not working in partial view as it's showing only menus, active is not enabled. I have dynamic menus which are coming from databse. So i have to use partial view.

Comment: I took the liberty to put the pointers that @Fergal noted in the answer for completion sake.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on Darin's example, here's the full class which adds additional optional parameters for RouteValues and HtmlAttributes on the helper.  In effect, it behaves just like the base ActionLink.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MYNAMESPACE.Helpers {
    public static class MenuExtensions {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                             string text, string action,
                                             string controller,
                                             object routeValues = null,
                                             object htmlAttributes = null) {
            var li = new TagBuilder("li");
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (string.Equals(currentAction,
                              action,
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController,
                              controller,
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                li.AddCssClass("active");
            }
            if (routeValues != null) {
                li.InnerHtml = (htmlAttributes != null)
                    ? htmlHelper.ActionLink(text,
                                            action,
                                            controller,
                                            routeValues,
                                            htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString()
                    : htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, 
                                            action, 
                                            controller, 
                                            routeValues).ToHtmlString();
            }
            else {
                li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, 
                                                     action, 
                                                     controller).ToHtmlString();
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And in the View folder's web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host ... />
  <pages ... >
    <namespaces>
      ...

      ...
      <add namespace="MYNAMESPACE.Helpers" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this InnerHtml if you'd like to include HTML formatting in your text;

```
li.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"" + new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action(action, controller).ToString() + "\">" + text + "</a>";
```

text could be "<b>Bold</b>Normal";

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for RC2** - For those wondering how to do this in MVC6 / Asp.Net 5 - similar but subtly different. There's now no `MvcHtmlString`, and the `RouteData` works completely differently. Also, the context object should now be `IHtmlContent` rather than `HtmlHelper`.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;

public static class MenuExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent MenuItem(
        this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string text,
        string action,
        string controller
    )
    {

        var li = new TagBuilder("li") { TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.Normal };
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var currentController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }


        li.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller));

        return li;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked great for me, even on a new Visual Studio 2013 MVC5/Bootstrap project. Note also that you could change the li.AddCssClass("active"); line to point to a custom class if you want to leave the Bootstrap "active" class alone. I added one called "activemenu" in the project's Site.css file and did any specific navbar styling changes I wanted there.

The line in the code above was just changed to this to get it all working:

```
li.AddCssClass("activemenu");
```

In Site.css I added a simple class for my purpose:

```
.activemenu {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Alternatively you could change the background color and/or border, etc...

Answer (score 0):

here is an extention on Darin's class to insert html in the link text rather than a simple text

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
    public static class MenuExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string html,
            string action,
            string controller
        )
        {
            var li = new TagBuilder("li");
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                li.AddCssClass("active");
            }
            //generate a unique id for the holder and convert it to string
            string holder = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string anchor = htmlHelper.ActionLink(holder, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
            //replace the holder string with the html
            li.InnerHtml = anchor.Replace(holder, html);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<ul>
    @Html.MenuItem("<span class'ClassName'>Home</span>", "Home", "Home")
</ul>
```