# MVC Layout Navbar Active Hide/Show DIV

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So i am going off of this example:

[better way to get active pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323021/better-way-to-get-active-page-link-in-mvc-3-razor)

What I'm trying to accomplish in my _Layout.cshtml is this:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div><a href="~/Home"><img src="~/Images/home_on.png" /></a></div>
<div><a href="~/Home"><img src="~/Images/home_off.png" /></a></div>
<div><a href="~/Home"><img src="~/Images/contact_on.png" /></a></div>
<div><a href="~/Home"><img src="~/Images/contact_off.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

The navbar div changes depending on the active page. If its home, then show "home_on.png" div. If its not display "home_off.png" and so forth.

Comment: What is your question or problem? Can you post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: I've posted a potential answer, but I've now realized that you aren't clear on whether or not you are using MVC routing or Angular routing.  You mention angularjs in the tag, but then mention a Razor layout page.  I think you need to clarify.

Comment: I deleted the angularjs tag. In the title I clearly stated MVC. I could have included "using razor syntax" somewhere I suppose. I will check the solution purposed below. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past.

Declare at the top of the layout:

```
@{
    var currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string ?? string.Empty;
    var currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string ?? string.Empty;

    string getImageSource(string basePath, string controller, string action)
    {
         var onOrOff = currentController.Equals(controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && currentAction.Equals(action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "on.png" : "off.png";
         return string.Format("{0}_{1}", basePath, onOrOff);
    }
}
```

Then you can render the appropriate image based off the expected controller and action:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div><a href="~/Home"><img src="@(getImageSource("~/Images/home", "Home", "Index"))" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="~/Home/Contact"><img src="@(getImageSource("~/Images/contact", "Home", "Contact"))" /></a></div>
</div>
```

I assume that the base `~/Home` URL is going to the `Index` action on the `HomeController`, and that `~/Home/Contact` is going to the `Contact` action on the `HomeController`.