# The Best Way to Highlight or Change Current Menu Item CSS Class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have read a few articles as I was searching for a solution.  They all seemed to favor a hard-coded or HTML Helper alternative; however, I wanted something simple and database driven.  This is **my** best solution (submitted as an answer, by me).

Here are some other articles' solutions:

- [An easy way to set the active tab using controllers and a usercontrol in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287679/an-easy-way-to-set-the-active-tab-using-controllers-and-a-usercontrol-in-asp-net)
- [asp.net mvc and css: Having menu tab stay highlighted on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475278/asp-net-mvc-and-css-having-menu-tab-stay-highlighted-on-selection)
- [ASP.NET MVC: Tabs ASCX - Adjust CSS class based on current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210900/asp-net-mvc-tabs-ascx-adjust-css-class-based-on-current-page?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a TempData down from one of your controllers like this:

```
TempData("CurrentPage") = "Nutrition"
```

Then, in your View add a conditional like this:

```
<ul>

@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item

    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData("CurrentPage")) And TempData("CurrentPage") = currentItem.NAV_Element) Then
        @<li><a class="current" href="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.NAV_Destination)">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.NAV_Element)</a></li>

    Else
        @<li><a href="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.NAV_Destination)">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.NAV_Element)</a></li>
    End If


Next

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this in the past by using the route values to generate a href and then setting the parent tab to active based on that.

This is a bootstrap flavoured version:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li><a href="/somepage">Some page</a></li>
     <li><a href="/someotherpage">Some other Page</a></li>
 </ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
          $('a[href="@Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values)"]').parents("li").addClass("active");
     };

 </script>
```

Si

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea.  I still prefer my solution because it doesn't depend on javascript as this one seems to.

Comment: -1 every `Action()` overload takes a string as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late to answer this but if you are using ASP MVC and looking for highlighting Menu items using controller and action, here is the solution which is working perfectly fine for me -

```
<li> <a href='@Url.Action("<action name>", "<controller name>")' class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() + ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "ControllerAction" ? "active" : "" )"> <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> <span>Signup</span> </a> </li>
```

---